# PHP OOP INSERT INTO only insert NULL in Database

Tags: mysql, database, oop

I'm trying to add members in my database using OOP, however it only insert NULL values
It works perfectly fine when I'm not using OOP

Here is my PHP code :

```
$request = $bdd->query('SELECT id_membre, prenom, nom, ville FROM client');

class Membre {
    private $_id;
    private $_prenom;
    private $_nom;
    private $_ville;
    /*HYDRATATION*/
    public function hydrate(array $donnees) {
        foreach($donnees as $key => $value) {
            $method = 'set'.ucfirst($key);
            if (method_exists($this, $method)) {

            $this->$method($value);
        }
    }
}
public function id() { return $this->_id; }
public function prenom() { return $this->_prenom; }
public function nom() { return $this->_nom; }
public function ville() { return $this->_ville; }

public function setId($id) {
    $this->_id = $id;
}
public function setPrenom($prenom) {
    $this->_prenom = $prenom;
}
public function setNom($nom) {
    $this->_nom = $nom;
}
public function setVille($ville) {
    $this->_ville = $ville;
}
}
```

That part seems to be working fine

```
class MembreManager {
    private $_bdd;
    public function __construct($bdd){
        $this->setBdd($bdd);
    }
    public function add(Membre $mbr) {
        $q = $this->_bdd->prepare("INSERT INTO client(prenom, nom, ville) 
        VALUES(:prenom, :nom, :ville)");

    $q->bindValue(':prenom', $mbr->prenom());
    $q->bindValue(':nom', $mbr->nom());
    $q->bindValue(':ville', $mbr->ville());
    $q->execute();
  }
}


$mbr = new Membre([
    'nom' => 'Name',
    'prenom' => 'Surname',
    'ville' => 'City',
]);

$manager = new MembreManager($bdd);

$manager->add($mbr);
   while($donnees = $request->fetch()) {
        $mbr = new Membre($donnees);
    }
```

Inserting values only seems to work when I manually input string in my Insert Into.

Comment: You are call a $request->fetch() but where is you execute for that particular fetch

Comment: Even after using a request->execute(); it still doesn't work

Comment: Look it is simple debugging, when you cann new Member see if a new member is created. even so, you get 4 columns as resultset from your select and that you trow in your new member class., which doesn't work at all, so define a new member the same way you add your static member and use for example new Membre([
    'nom' => $donnees['nom'],

Comment: I'm not sure about where to actualy put my new Membre, because when I leave it at the same place in my code it says $donnees is an undefined variable

Comment: I am also  unsure, because i expect that your select gives any Rows back so that the while loop can work. So you have to debug it properly, check every variable if it has what you want and see that every code line works properly.